# How do I get text to overlay on top of an image in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, image, dreamweaver

**How would I go about and get text to overlay on top of an image in dreamweaver? 
Like the linked image below:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GvkW.png

Here is what my code looks like:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<main>
<header>
<img src="images/headerimage.jpg" alt="" height="500" width="1280">
</header>
<h1>Hidden Gems of</h1>
<h2>Canada</h2>
</main>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0;
    }
main{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    }
header{
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FF751F;
    margin-top: 23px;
    }
h1{
    font-family: "Ailerons";
    font-size: 83px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    text-shadow: 7px 7px 15px #000;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: 314px;
    }
h2{
    font-family: "SkolaSans";
    font-size: 44px;
    font-weight:100;
    text-shadow: 7px 7px 10px #000;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: 536px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set your image as a background image in your CSS.

First put your text inside the `<header>` tag and remove the image, like so:

```
<header>
    <h1>Hidden Gems of</h1>
    <h2>Canada</h2>
</header>
```

Then in your CSS add the header image as a background:

```
header{
    width: 1280px;
    height: 500px;
    background:url('images/headerimage.jpg') no-repeat center;
    /* 'no-repeat' stops the image tiling inside its container, and 'center' will position the image in the middle of its containing div */
    margin-top: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Tried that out and unfortunately it didn't work. When I viewed it in my browser there was no image or text.

Comment: Is your css file in the same folder as your html? The path is relative, so if you have a css folder the url might need to be `'../images/headerimage.jpg'`

Comment: That corrected the problem!! Thank you very much for your help.